# Why does this for loop work

Tags: java, loops

I have this code:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k>-3; k=-2;); {
System.out.println(k);
}
```

The output is negative four. I don't understand why this code still runs even though there is a semi colon after the statements in the for loop.

Comment: Are you sure it's `k=-2` and not `k-=2`? The first would output nothing, and the second would output negative four.

Comment: I'm debating whether to downvote all the answers that miss that...

Comment: Yeah, `k=-2` would give you an infinite loop, because `k` is always `== -2` which is `>-3`...

Comment: Actually, the code won't even compile because of the `;` after `-2`. So many eyes on this, and nobody sees it, because we all assume that OP is thoughtful enough to post a compilable question.

Comment: k=-2 was a typo. My bad. This was an old exam question.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed in the comments, there are a few issues on top of the loop issue. First, the third semicolon is a syntax error. Second, it's supposed to be `k-=2` instead of `k=-2` or the loop will never end.

Once those are cleared, this code is equivalent to:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k>-3; k-=2);

{
  System.out.println(k);
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k>-3; k-=2);

System.out.println(k);
```

Which is the same as:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k>-3; k-=2) {
}

System.out.println(k);
```

By using a semicolon after the for loop you asked for a for loop that does nothing. The brackets around `System.out.println(k)` after that are just normal brackets. You can put any code in its own scope, even without a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't do what you say it does. Really, try running it. You probably meant to type minus-equals (`-=`) instead of equals-minus (`=-`).

Next, remove the semicolon after the for loop. See the other 5 answers for an explanation of this.

Comment: great! i completely missed it :D

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo. I was going over an old exam so I wanted to just know the logic behind the question. Am trying it without the semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `;` semicolon after your if-condition. Therefore your condition terminates immediately and the next block, which is delimited with `{` and `}` is executed 100% of the time.

Change this

```
for (k=0; k>-3; k=-2;);
```

To this

```
for (k=0; k>-3; k=-2;)
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop does not actually run. Well, it does, but not the loop inside the code. Here is what happens:

```
int k;
for(k=0; k>-3; k-=2;); // <-- this line is what is repeated
```

- Loop 1: k = 0 which is greater than -3. Loop does nothing.
- Loop 2: k = -2 which is greater than -3. Loop does nothing.
- Loop 3: k = -4 which is NOT greater than -3, and so it exits.

Next, it hits the `System.out.println` statement, which will print `k` (-4).

Answer (score 0):

The loop body is empty as you suspect. It runs to completion, with two complete iterations (0, -2). After that, the  value of k is -4, so the loop exits. Then, you have an anonymous block that only gets executed once, as any normal statement. That block contains your println that shows the value of k after the loop, which was your negative four.

Answer (score 0):

your code is rewritable as

```
int k;
for (k=0; k>-3; k=-2;)
{
 // do nothing
}
System.out.println(k);
```

but probably you want get somewthing like this:

```
int k;
for (k=0; k>-3; k-=2) {

    System.out.println(k);
}
```

without `;` before `{`

**edited** after djechlin's comment: nice catch!